# In AWS Lambda, Why is the function's module unable to be imported?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting an error on AWS Console, when testing the deployment package:

[image]

```
{
 "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

---

The deployment-package.zip contains:

- A python2.7 function.py
- VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages's content (not the directory itself)

---

I believe to have followed packaging instructions correctly:

[AWS's Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html),

On MacOS, I created .zip file with the Python2.7 code:

```
$ zip ../path/to/my/deployment-package.zip ./my_function.py
```

Then added the virtualenv's modules to it:

```
$ cd ../path/to/my/py2.7_virtualenv
$ zip -ru ../path/to/deployment-package.zip *
```

The result is a .zip file:

```
$ ls -l
$ -rw-r--r--   1 user  staff  9036477 Feb 26 00:15 deployment-package.zip
```

That contains the code and the modules:

```
$ unzip deployment-package.zip
...
$ ls 
deployment-package.zip      XlsxWriter-0.9.6.dist-info
_markerlib                  pip
boto3                       pip-7.1.0.dist-info
boto3-1.4.4.dist-info       pkg_resources
botocore                    python_dateutil-2.6.0.dist-info
botocore-1.5.18.dist-info   s3transfer
concurrent                  s3transfer-0.1.10.dist-info
dateutil                    setuptools
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The steps were correct.

The problem was in the package being used, it was an old version stored in S3.
The new version was in the process of being uploaded when the test was run.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a .py file in your ls output. There should be a py file to match what was specified as the handler under "Lambda function handler and role".

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Edited the output for brevity and forgot about it.